# jQuery change multiple image src on change of file input

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, file-upload, src

Im trying to change the style of my default file upload to a preview based on. 
On change of a input field I want to update the src of the preview image. Thats working but just for the first type of file input. I want to be flexible if i want to add a upload input. Can you help me to find my faulty thinking?

HTML

```
<div class="file-uploader">

<label name="upload-label" class="upload-img-btn">
<input type="file" class="upload-field-1" style="display:none;" />
<img class="preview-1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3a/Torchlight_viewmag_plus.png" style="width:150px!important;" />
</label>

<label name="upload-label" class="upload-img-btn">
<input type="file" class="upload-field-2" style="display:none;" />
<img class="preview-2" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3a/Torchlight_viewmag_plus.png" style="width:150px!important;" />
</label>

</div>
```

Script

```
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();            
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('.file-uploader .preview-'+num_id).attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    var num_id = $(".file-uploader input[type='file']").attr('class').match(/\d+/); 
    $(".file-uploader .upload-field-"+num_id).change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
```

Comment: You need to pass 'num_id' to readURL(). It should be readURL(this, num_id);

Comment: I tried this before too but doesnt change anything. :(

Comment: `$('.file-uploader .preview-'+num_id)` - This line won't be getting num_id, so you need to pass that variable. Also, try to debug using console.log() and check the flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();            
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var num = $(input).attr('class').split('-')[2];
                $('.file-uploader .preview-'+num).attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    } 
    
    $("[class^=upload-field-]").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="file-uploader">

<label name="upload-label" class="upload-img-btn">
<input type="file" class="upload-field-1" style="display:none;" />
<img class="preview-1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3a/Torchlight_viewmag_plus.png" style="width:150px!important;" />
</label>

<label name="upload-label" class="upload-img-btn">
<input type="file" class="upload-field-2" style="display:none;" />
<img class="preview-2" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3a/Torchlight_viewmag_plus.png" style="width:150px!important;" />
</label>

</div>
```

Please check the code might help you out

Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Best regards Lukas